# How to use Bootstrap with less in an express node js project?

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm already using bootstrap.css. But i would like to surcharge the less variables without using bootstrap customize editor.

I would like to add a less file in my project. My project is a simple nodejs project with express and harpejs.

Where to find the less file ? Using express it will compile it when i will deploy the project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using [bower](http://bower.io).

```
npm install -g bower
bower install bootstrap
```

You will then find all the less files in `bower_components/bootstrap/less/*`. Copy the `bootstrap.less` file to your CSS directory and make alterations (make sure the paths are correct).

You can then look at using some [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) tasks to get the less to build.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the awnser. I'm using harpejs wich already have a less compiler, how can i symply get the bootstrap.less file and variables.less file. Is it possible to juste use this two file ? No problems with font or glyphicons compile ?

Comment: If you keep the `bower_components/` directory in your public path (which you should). The font/glyhicons are linked relatively, so they should just work.